# Как получить продукты Woocommerce по атрибуту?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как правильно составить параметры для `new WP_Query($params)`, что бы получить продукты из определённой категории и с нужным атрибутом. 
Использую такие параметры:

```
array(4) {
  ["post_type"]=>string(7) "product"
  ["cat"]=>int(7)
  ["posts_per_page"]=>int(100)
  ["meta_query"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["relation"]=>string(3) "AND"
    [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["meta_key"]=>string(15) "pa_video-genres"
        ["value"]=>string(3) "pop"
        ["compare"]=>string(1) "="
    }
  }
}
```

или

```
array(4) {
  ["post_type"]=>string(7) "product"
  ["cat"]=>int(7)
  ["posts_per_page"]=>int(100)
  ["tax_query"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["relation"]=>string(3) "AND"
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["tax_query"]=>string(15) "pa_video-genres"
      ["field"]=>string(4) "slug"
      ["terms"]=>string(3) "pop"
    }
  }
}
```

которые не дают результата. В чём ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При создании товара, его атрибуты сохраняются в виде массива _product_attributes, поэтому их сперва нужно доставать из этого массива.
Или использовать такой код, который будет создавать отдельную запись по каждому атрибуту в таблице postmeta.

```
/**
 *  Сохраняем атрибуты товара в виде мета данных к записи для того, чтобы использовать их в сортировке и поиске
 */
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_woocommerce_attr_to_meta' );
function save_woocommerce_attr_to_meta( $post_id ) {
    // Получаем названия атрибутов .. Для каждого элемента получаем индекс и название атрибута
    // Затем используем индекс для получения соответствующего отправленного значения из массива attribute_values.
    if (isset($_REQUEST['attribute_names'])) {
        foreach( $_REQUEST['attribute_names'] as $index => $value ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $value, $_REQUEST['attribute_values'][$index] );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$loop = new WP_Query(
    array( 
        'post_type' => 'product', 
        'posts_per_page' => 30,
        'tax_query'      => array(
            'relation'      => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
                'field'        => 'id',
                'terms'        => 157
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'pa_show_main_slider',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'da'
            ),
        )
    )
);
```